# Docker CLI does not Understand AWS CLI SSO Credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker-compose, single-sign-on, amazon-ecs

I am using Single sign-on (SSO) authentication with AWS.

In the terminal, I sign into my SSO account, successfully:

```
aws sso login --profile dev
```

Navigating to the directory of the docker-compose.yml file, and using Docker in an Amazon ECS context, the command `docker compose up -d` fails with:

```
NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain. Deprecated.
        For verbose messaging see aws.Config.CredentialsChainVerboseErrors
```

I have deleted the old (non-SSO) access keys and profiles in:

```
~/.aws/config

~/.aws/credentials
```

So now all that is present in the above directories is my SSO account.

Before SSO (using IAM users), `docker compose up -d` worked as expected, so I believe the problem is that Docker is having difficulty connecting to AWS via SSO on the CLI.

Any help here is much appreciated.

Docs on Docker ECS integration: https://docs.docker.com/cloud/ecs-integration/

The `docker-compose.yml` file looks like this:

```
version: "3.4"

x-aws-vpc: "vpc-xxxxx"
x-aws-cluster: "test"
x-aws-loadbalancer: "test-nlb"

services:
  test:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      target: development
    image: xxx.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/xxx:10
    environment:
      - AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}
      - AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}
      - ENABLE_SWAGGER=${ENABLE_SWAGGER:-true}
      - LOGGING_LEVEL=${LOGGING_LEVEL:-INFO}
    ports:
      - "9090:9090"
```

Comment: Are you doing something in docker compose to set `AWS_PROFILE=dev`?

Comment: @jordanm I am not setting AWS_PROFILE=dev anywhere, maybe I should? I have added the docker-compose.yml file to the question for posteriority

Comment: If you don't set the profile it will attempt to use the one named `default`, but `default` is not the profile you are authenticating.

Comment: Seeing your dockerfile, you are not sharing ~/.aws with the container, and you haven't mentioned setting those env variables.

Comment: I just added `AWS_PROFILE=dev` to the `docker-compose.yml file`, but `docker compose up -d` still returns the same error. For those other env variables, I have removed them now as they are no longer needed. For what is worth, the above runs fine when using IAM role access keys and secrets.